# Is this a correct implementation of operator<< / >>?

Tags: c++, math, operator-overloading, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

are these correct implementations of the operator<< and >> for bitshifting? for some reason, in my operator/, where it only involves these 2 operators, something is allowing for a silly jump that is causing division to be done incorrectly.

```
    // the value is stored msb in a list of uint8_t
    // so 0x123456 will be stored in the list as {0x12, 0x34, 0x56}
    integer operator<<(size_t shift){
        std::list <uint8_t> out = value;
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < (shift >> 3); i++)
            out.push_back(0);
        shift &= 7;
        if (shift){
            out.push_front(0);
            std::list <uint8_t>::iterator i = out.begin(), j = out.end();
            i++; j--;
            for(; i != j; i++){
                uint8_t temp = *i >> (8 - shift);
                --i;
                *i += temp;
                i++;
                *i = (uint8_t) (*i << shift);
            }
            uint8_t temp = *i >> (8 - shift);
            i--;
            *i += temp;
            i++;
            *i <<= shift;
        }
        return integer(out);
    }

    integer operator>>(size_t shift){
        std::list <uint8_t> out = value;
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < (shift >> 3); i++)
            out.pop_back();
        shift &= 7;
        if (shift){
            std::list <uint8_t>::reverse_iterator i = out.rbegin(), j = out.rend();
            j--;
            for(; i != j; i++){
                *i >>= shift;
                i++;
                uint8_t temp = *i << (8 - shift);
                i--;
                *i += temp;
            }
            *j >>= shift;
        }
        return integer(out);
    }
```

heres what im doing:

```
integer(1234567) / integer(6)

inside division algorithm (long division):

numerator       largest multiple of denomiator < numeator

12d687          0c0000
06d687          060000
d687            c000
1687            0c00
0a87            0600
0487            0300
0187            0c        <-- where did this come from??
017b            0180
```

is the error in one of the operators shown or in some other operator?

heres my entire code: http://ideone.com/ncq9S

Comment: I would use an `std::vector` in this algorithm. I'd also get rid of the statement `i = i`.

Comment: i would use vector too, but i need to push front some values

Comment: `std::deque` has almost as much efficiency as `std::vector` but also allows both `push_front` and `push_back`.

Comment: im not asking about what container to use. im trying to figure out whats wrong with the actions the computer is taking due to my commands

Comment: @calccrypto: are you ordering us to please shut up in the comments?

Comment: You should give a description of what the underlying data structure is, what the operation is meant to do and how you are trying to perform the operation.

Comment: @calccrypto: Have a downvote. How many times are you going to implement division in C++, and how many times are you going to post your code with a generic 'it is not working' type question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template <typename T>
```

Does this really need to be parameterized? It would seem that any shift quantity can be stored in a `size_t`, and converting to `size_t` implicitly or explicitly would be a good idea before starting the rest of the process.

```
integer operator<<(T shift){
```

Usually binary `operator` functions are best implemented as non-member `friend`s. For example, fewer conversions are considered when producing the `this` pointer than for generic operands. I'd write `friend integer operator<< ( integer lhs, size_t shift )`.

```
    std::list <uint8_t> out = value;
```

If you use a `friend` and pass-by-value, then this copy is made implicitly. The compiler also has an easier time eliminating it if you are really just modifying one object, e.g. `q = q << 3`.

```
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < (shift >> 3); i++)// get rid of bytes if shift > 8
```

Be careful in the loop condition. You're applying an operator to a high-level type, which might cause an expensive computation (or even endless recursion if `T` is `integer`!

```
    shift &= 7;                                   // shift by less than a byte
```

At this point, if `shift == 0` you are done. Best to insert a conditional `return` here. Also, now the range is *really* limited, so assign to a narrower type than `T`.

```
    out.push_front(0);                            // extra byte for overflow
```

This is only necessary if the byte will be nonzero. Probably best to special-case the first operation and make the `push_front` conditional, instead of special-casing the last.

… Hmm, it looks like the `operator>>` is being exercised more… skipping to that…

```
    for(; i != j; i++){
        i++;
        uint8_t temp = *i << (8 - shift);
        i--;
        *i += temp;
    }
    *j >>= shift;
```

Clearly the `>>` operator is missing from the loop. Try `*i = *i >> shift + temp`. Also, I don't see how the list ever gets shorter. Is that done in `integer::integer( list<…> )`?

However, I can't really see what produces the behavior in the posted output. The leading zero is probably a result of the unconditional `push_front` in `operator<<`, but the pattern I'd expect is `c`, `6`, `3`, `18`, `c`, …. You don't seem to be repeating any sequence, but instead jump randomly.

Maybe the division code, or the class constructor could provide clues.

Comment: @calc: This isn't optimization, it's cleanup. Cutting out the fat *without* considering performance will expose the actual algorithm and hopefully, its bugs.

Comment: oops. i fixed `operator<<` i hope. i edited my question so that some of the changes you suggested have been done. theres also a link to the full code. now the operator/ works, but im getting the wrong answer

Comment: and yes, there is a function called `clean()` that removes bytes at the front that == 0, as shown in the full code